# As variáveis de uma função são excluídas automaticamente após o seu término?

Tags: php, funções, desempenho, memória

Estou desenvolvendo uma função que possui variáveis que carregam uma grande quantidade de dados e como essas variáveis são utilizadas somente dentro dessa função não faz sentido elas continuarem ocupando espaço em memória, a principio realizei a exclusão das mesmas utilizando a função `unset()`, mas me veio a dúvida: "Após uma função terminar a variáveis da mesma são apagadas automaticamente assim como no fim do script como um todo, ou o uso do `unset()` é realmente necessário?"

A função segue mais ou menos a seguinte estrutura:

```
<?php
    function metodox($x,$y,$z)
    {
       //Nesse ponto a variável return recebe o resultado de uma requisição a uma API retornado pelo metodoy
       $return = $metodoy($url);
       $dados = json_decode($return);
     //Operações sobre o conteúdo da variável $dados

       //Ao fim realizo os issets
       isset($return);
       isset($dados);
     }
```

Não coloquei a função original pois a mesma é bem extensa, porém, a estrutura básica é essa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS variáveis dentro de funções são eliminadas automaticamente ao termino de execução, em resumo ela só está viva enquanto a função estiver sendo executada.

**Referencia:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082870/does-php-free-local-variables-immediately-after-the-function-ends

Porem caso seja fora de uma função recomendo o uso da função [`unset();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unset.php).

Um dica que você pode fazer é trabalhar com vetores, por exemplo: `$array['return'];` e `$array['dados'];` no final usar apenas um `unset($array);` com isso eliminaria tudo em apenas um variável.

Comment: Eu sempre acabo trocando os nomes `unset()` por `isset()`, já corrigi o erro na pergunta. Minha dúvida na realidade é o que acontece com variáveis de um método após o seu término, elas são automaticamente excluídas?

Comment: @ThiagoDrulla, sim eu vi que corrigiu adicionei o que queria sabe no final da resposta. (mas é umas das opções que pode fazer)

Comment: Caso eu não realize o `unset()` no fim do método, as variáveis vão continuar ocupando espaço em memória até o fim do script?

Comment: Se for dentro de uma função ela será excluída automaticamente, (cara agora que vi que está dentro de uma função); ela só estará viva enquanto a função estiver em execução, após o termino dela será limpa a variável.

Comment: exatamente isso que eu queria saber, coloque essa sua última explicação na resposta se possível

Comment: @ThiagoDrulla mudei a resposta, e adicionei uma referencia do stack gringo. da uma lida nos comentários da pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

A pergunta está um pouco confusa porque ela fala em método e usa um exemplo que parece ser uma função (poderia ser só um trecho de uma classe).

As variáveis locais de uma função ou método deixam de ser visíveis e saem de escopo quando termina por completo a execução da função. Possivelmente termina o tempo de vida também, porém isto depende de alguns fatores como a existência de uma referência para um objeto apontado por aquela variável.

As variáveis que não são locais à função ou método continuam existindo normalmente.

Você não precisa tentar remover as variável locais, e isto nem faz muito sentido.

Parâmetros são considerados variáveis locais.

Quase sempre que usa um `unset()` está fazendo algo errado, não importa em qual variável. Quase todos os casos é gambiarra para contornar um problema e o certo seria resolver o problema.

Comment: Realmente, se trata de uma função, vou corrigir o erro na pergunta. Não costumo utilizar o `unset()` pois pelo que vi, inclusive em sua resposta em uma pergunta sobre o uso dela, o uso da mesma pode levar a um gasto maior de memória para a sua execução.

Answer (score 1):

O comportamento de `unset()` pode variar dentro de uma função dependendo do tipo de variável que você está tentando destruir.

Se utilizar `unset()` em uma variável global dentro de uma função, somente a variável local será destruída. A variável no ambiente que foi chamada terá o mesmo valor como antes da execução de `unset()`.

```
<?php
function destroi_teste()
{
    global $teste;
    unset($teste);
}

$teste= 'bar';
destroi_teste();
echo $teste;
?>
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

```
bar
```

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unset.php